# How to authorize user in MediaWiki 1.19 without password?

Tags: php, authorization, mediawiki, session-cookies

In my plugin I have only username or email and I have to authorize that user. I found next issue, but it didn't work for me:

```
    class ApiPlugin extends ApiBase {
        public function execute() {
            $params = $this->extractRequestParams();

            switch ( $params['do'] ) {
                case 'login':
                    // Registering. Works fine.
                    $user = User::newFromName( 'admin' );
                    $user->setEmail( admin@email.com );
                    $user->setRealName( 'admin' );
                    $uid = $user->idForName();

                    if ( $uid === 0 ) {
                        $user->addToDatabase();
                        $user->setPassword( generate_password() );
                        $user->saveSettings();
                    }
                    $ssu = new SiteStatsUpdate( 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );
                    $ssu->doUpdate();

                    if ($user->isLoggedIn()) $user->doLogout();

                    //Logging in.
                    $id = User::idFromName('admin');
                    $user->setID($id);
                    $user->loadFromId();

                    $user->setToken();
                    $user->saveSettings();

                    wfSetupSession();
                    $user->setCookies();
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Also, another issue was getting password hash straight from DB, but it is barbarism...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: _How_ does it not work?  Also, you might want to provide a little more context.  I assume this code is from a [UserLoadFromSession](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/UserLoadFromSession) hook?

Comment: It is API based plugin. Added some code.
> How does it not work?
After invoking `api.php?action=ApiPlugin&do=login` I'm still logged in as anonymous.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  Are you getting any new cookies back?

Comment: No, just checked, no any new cookies

Comment: Strange. Could you enable [debug logging](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Debugging#Logging), at least for the log group `cookie`, and see if there are any lines beginning with `setcookie:` in the log?

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say... I just separated register and login functions, and it began to work. o_O
Anyway thank you for you time.

PS May be it is not recommend to use one variable $user in this case?

Comment: That could well be the case.  Nice to see the problem solved, anyway.

Comment: Does OAuth help nowadays? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OAuth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few days I tried to separate code and... profit!

```
class ApiPlugin extends ApiBase {
    public function execute() {
        $params = $this->extractRequestParams();

        switch ( $params['do'] ) {
            case 'register':
                // Registering. Works fine.
                $user = User::newFromName( 'admin' );
                $user->setEmail( admin@email.com );
                $user->setRealName( 'admin' );
                $uid = $user->idForName();

                if ( $uid === 0 ) {
                    $user->addToDatabase();
                    $user->setPassword( generate_password() );
                    $user->saveSettings();
                }
                $ssu = new SiteStatsUpdate( 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );
                $ssu->doUpdate();
            case 'authorise':
                if ($user->isLoggedIn()) $user->doLogout();
                wfSetupSession();
                //Logging in.
                $id = User::idFromName('admin');
                $user->setID($id);
                $user->loadFromId();

                $user->setToken();
                $user->saveSettings();

                $user->setCookies();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```